# Unable to create Xpath to locate individual value

Tags: xpath

I found some elements where several documents within. How can i locate individual document by creating an xpath expression, as in email and phone?
I tried with:

```
//div[@class="professional-info-content"]/text()
```

but it gives all the docs.

Here are the elements:

```
<div class='professional-info-content'><b>Impressum:</b><br/>hokon
<br/>Jörn Brenscheidt GmbH
<br/>Wasserbank 21
<br/>D-58456 Witten Herbede
<br/>
<br/>Tel.: 0049 (0) 2302 780100
<br/>Fax: 0049 (0) 2302 780110
<br/>E-Mail: info@hokon.de
<br/>www.hokon.de</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: Sorry sir choroba, for not being explicit with my asking. I expect to scrape email and phone number only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/div[@class="professional-into-content"]/text()` returns a node list of all the text nodes under the div. To get only a specific one, you can specify an index, e.g.:

```
/div[@class="professional-into-content"]/text()[6]
```

returns the telephone number and

```
/div[@class="professional-into-content"]/text()[8]
```

the email.